# Bootstrap: How to position an element with 100% width on the bottom of a card with fixed height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-position

I have a simple card with fixed height. Now I want to position a toolbar on the bottom of the card. The toolbar needs to have the full width of the card-body. But it does not work:

```
<div class="card" style="height: 300px;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
      toolbar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seams, the 100% width of my toolbar references the card, not the card-body. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding left:0 and right:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this I hope this work

```
     <div class="card-footer text-muted"> toolbar </div>
```